# Increasing footer widget width and centering menu (Wordpress)

Tags: css, wordpress, menu, widget, footer

I am currently trying to get my footer menu to center and appear all on one line. Currently, it is on 2 lines for some reason.

The website is: http://museiam.ca/

I am trying to achieve this (image): http://museiam.ca/wp-content/uploads/LookBookPage_1.jpg

The theme I am using allows the option of 3 OR 4 widgets in the footer area. I currently have it set to 3. The menu itself is in one widget including the links Customer Care - Newsletter, where the Follow Us link is in another HTML text widget with all the social icons. I am trying to put everything on one line and centered like in the picture with equal padding.

I have tried to increase the widget of the menu width but to no success. Here is the CSS I tried:

```
.widget widget_nav_menu .menu-footer-1-container {
width: 800px !important;
}
```

I am open to any input or solution to achieve my desired look. I appreciate and thank you for all looking.

Answer (score 0):

Look for this `.container_12 .grid_4` and change the width to 100%

```
.container_12 .grid_4 {
width: 100%;
}
```

Also, you have another widget there which has an empty text post, remove that.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 3 'grid_4' divs to fill 'container_12' parent div. What you need to do (from my perspective) is the following:

1. Use a single 'grid_12' div to wrap the menu, instead of dividing it into 3 'grid_4'.
2. Then, give menu UL 'align: center'
3. For centering li children do 'display: inline-block' on them (I think you already did this one).

Comment: Thanks for helping me understand a bit better. Is there anyway to just remove the grids and move the footer to the container? Or will that remove widgets from the footer completely?

Comment: 'grid_12' div will be your container though. If you remove it you probably will get unwanted/strange results on responsiveness.